# What happened for them to ban Apparition in Hogwarts?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts, apparition

In the new trailer for the new Fantastic Beasts film, it shows people apparating into Hogwarts yet apparition is banned on the Howarts grounds, so I was wondering if anyone knew why it got banned or what happened?

Comment: apparating isnt banned, its just prevented.

Comment: Not allowing unauthorised entry is School Safeguarding Policy #1 in most school.

Comment: See also [Can Ministry officials Apparate inside Hogwarts?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/183632/5930)  I think there's a slim majority leaning towards the view that the bridge is at the border of the Hogwarts grounds, so the people in question *aren't* apparating inside Hogwarts.

Comment: And in particular [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/183719/5930) which establishes (via Pottermore) that the anti-apparition charms at Hogwarts have always been there.

Answer (score 4):

## It’s never said - presumably it’s just for security reasons.

While it’s said many times that it’s not possible to Apparate or Disapparate within Hogwarts, it’s never explained when or why this enchantment was put into place. However, it seems logical enough to protect against unwanted people just Apparating into Hogwarts whenever they want to. Otherwise, people could Apparate in and steal things, or kidnap students, or anything really... The Dark Lord could Apparate in, kill Harry Potter, then Disapparate and make a clean getaway.

*Note: Apparition wouldn’t be considered “banned” since “banned” means something that people are capable of doing but aren’t allowed to. The enchantment on Hogwarts* entirely prevents *people from Apparating in or out (unless the headmaster lifts the enchantment).*

## There are also anti-Apparition spells on many wizarding homes.

Having an enchantment preventing people from Apparating into somewhere isn’t in any way unique to Hogwarts - many wizarding homes have it as well.

> “Professor, why couldn’t we just Apparate directly into your old colleague’s house?’
>
> ‘Because it would be quite as rude as kicking down the front door,’ said Dumbledore. ‘Courtesy dictates that we offer fellow wizards the opportunity of denying us entry. In any case, most wizarding dwellings are magically protected from unwanted Apparators. At Hogwarts, for instance –’
>
> ‘– you can’t Apparate anywhere inside the buildings or grounds,’ said Harry quickly. ‘Hermione Granger told me.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince, Chapter 4 (Horace Slughorn)*</sup></sub>

Most likely in those cases it’s also a security measure (and to a lesser extent, a way of preventing unwanted visitors from literally popping in on them).

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is: it's done for security purpose. If one read the books, one will see why it's so important:

- Kidnapping (Harry thought he had been kidnapped in the 5th book: he dreamt of being a snake attacking Ron's father)
- Invasion (Draco Malfoy did invade Hogwarts with some Death Eaters; but it took him a school year to do so)

Last but not least: Apparition is dangerous. Many split. I do understand why Hogwarts doesn't want youngsters to do it.

But there is more:

### The Rules of Apparition at Hogwarts

#### Anti-Apparition Charms are as old as Hogwarts

> Some rode broomsticks (a difficult feat when carrying trunks and
> pets); others commandeered enchanted carts and, later, carriages; some
> attempted to Apparate (often with disastrous effects, as **the castle
> and grounds have always been protected with Anti-Apparition Charms**),
> others rode a variety of magical creatures.
>
> **Source**: [Pottermore](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/the-hogwarts-express); The Hogwarts Express

#### Hermione about the Jinxes

Harry Potter and The Half-Blood Prince, Chapter 4

> Dumbledore said to Harry:
>
> "In any case, most Wizarding dwellings are magically protected from
> unwanted Apparators. At Hogwarts, for instance —"
>
> "— you can’t Apparate anywhere inside the buildings or grounds," said
> Harry quickly. "Hermione Granger told me."
>
> **Harry Potter and The Half-Blood Prince, Chapter 4**

#### Jinxes lifted for Apparition learning

We know that the jinxes were removed to allow some Apparition training in the Great Hall. That happened in HP 6.

### Movie possibilities

So how does it come, that they can Apparate in the movie trailer at Hogwarts grounds?

1. The filmmakers don't give a shit
2. The bridge isn't part of the jinxed grounds
3. The jinxes were temporarily removed
4. They don't Apparate / use different magic to Apparate (Dobby and others are able to Apparate; and Dumbledore can, using "portus", teleport at Hogwarts as well)

Answer (score 3):

Security reasons. Apperation is instant travel. They have wards to prevent it.

> "As you may know, it is usually impossible to Apparate or Disapparate within Hogwarts. The Headmaster has lifted this enchantment, purely within the Great Hall, for one hour, so as to enable you to practise. May I emphasise that you will not be able to Apparate outside the walls of this Hall, and that you would be unwise to try." *Half-Blood Prince, Chapter 18, Birthday Surprises*

As you can see, this is under the control of the headmaster. It's also dangerous if you're inexperienced (which the students are), so for the sake of safety it was probably also disallowed. Add to that crowded hallways with students teleporting  everywhere, and if it were allowed, any student close to getting caught out after lights out that could would just apperate back to bed. It would also mean that students could leave at any time, instantly.

It keeps the students in, and makes sure that they see people coming.

I watched the trailer in question. They do NOT apperate inside. They apperate OUTSIDE and walk in. The wards are likely stronger inside than out, so it's still a show of power.

Answer (score 1):

Apparition isn't 'banned' in Hogwarts, in the sense of a rule against it or something, the wards flat-out prevent it.

Seriously, this is a big point in many of the books.  As Hermione has said, "You can't appirate or disapparate inside Hogwarts."

Yes, there are a few cases where this happened, but they are all very unusual edge cases.  The biggest one is Montague, which is explained in [another question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/127333/656).

That said, the movie universe is different from the book universe.  There's also every chance that the wards can be taken down (either completely or partially) to allow Appiration within Hogwarts.